# How to get the list of users who have edit the pages in confluence?

Tags: mysql, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I need to get the list of users who are just viewing the pages(all spaces/one space) but not editing the pages(all spaces/one space) in confluence and i want to get the list of users who are editing the pages.So,i logged into my servers mysql db and opened the database schema and have run the below query.

```
SELECT distinct u.lower_user_name, l.successdate FROM cwd_user u LEFT JOIN logininfo l ON u.user_name = l.usernameJOIN cwd_membership m ON u.id = m.child_user_id JOIN cwd_group g ON m.parent_id = g.id JOIN SPACEPERMISSIONS sp ON g.group_name = sp.permgroupname WHERE permtype='USECONFLUENCE' order by u.lower_user_name;
```

This is giving the list of users which is more than the actual users in my confluence. But, my requirement is different and i could not find any related documents or queries from the below link "https://confluence.atlassian.com/disc/administration-tips/obtaining-confluence-instance-metrics". I am sure am running in correct schema and i cannot use any plugins for this.

Answer (score 0):

By default Confluence doesn't store content view statistic in Database and I believe if you just need to find the viewer, you have to use third party plugins ([here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Confluence-SQL-query-for-pageviews-by-user/qaq-p/47969)).

Comment: i have installed the viewtracker plugin, but i dono if i have to use in every page to know about the page details or generically for pages in a space

Comment: I added the supporting plugins of servicerocket and viewtracker support plugin, then i could see viewtracker tab in space administrator, but there the reports are available but it says 0 for every entry

Comment: Well unfortunately, I don't know how these plugins work but I know about the Confluence core functionality ;-)